# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN>'

Tags: pycharm, google-colaboratory, linear-regression, valueerror

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    
    car_data = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/"
    auto_data = pd.read_csv(car_data, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['mpg',   `  `'cylinders', 'displacement','horsepower', 'weight', 'acceleration','model year', 'origin', 'car    `  `name'])
    auto_data = auto_data[auto_data['horsepower'] != '?']
    auto_data['horsepower'] = auto_data['horsepower'].astype(float)
    auto_data = auto_data.drop('car name', axis=1)
    features = auto_data.drop('mpg', axis=1)
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    data = scaler.fit_transform(auto_data)
    s_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=auto_data.columns)
    
    fs_data = np.array([s_data])
    
    x = fs_data[:, :-1]
    (https://www.stackoverflow.com/)y = fs_data[:, -1]
    
    w = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    b = 0
    
    alpha = 0.01
    
    for i in range(50000):
        w = w - alpha * (1 / len(data)) * np.dot(np.transpose(np.dot(x, w)+b-y), x)
        b = b - alpha * (1 / len(data)) * sum(np.dot(x, w)+b-y)
    print(w, b)
```

I keep getting the same error, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried to change the values, and I was able to normalize it in pycharm but then it normalizes in colab it donest work

```
`
    `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

          7 auto_data = auto_data[auto_data['horsepower'] != '?']
    ----> 8 auto_data['horsepower'] = auto_data['horsepower'].astype(float)
          9 auto_data = auto_data.drop('car name', axis=1)
         10 features = auto_data.drop('mpg', axis=1)

     /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype,     copy, skipna)
       1199     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr.dtype) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
       1200         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
    -> 1201         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
       1202 
       1203     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: -//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN>
```

Comment: Please format your post and code blocks properly.

Comment: sorry still new to formatting i just need help plz